# Can I find an element inside a ref object in react?

Tags: reactjs, ref

I tried to getElementByClassName using ref but the error is getElementByClassName is not a function, I cannot use ref to the specified element. Can someone help ?

```
const ref = useRef(null);
//...
const handleAction = () => {
    if(ref.current) {
        console.log('I get here')
        const elem = ref.current.getElementByClassName('myClass')
    }
}

return (<div>
     <component ref={ref} />
     <button onClick={handleAction} />
</div>)
```

I got to the console.log('i get here')

Comment: can you add the full code on how you are using the ref in your component ?

Comment: Looks to be caused by typo, `getElementByClassName` should be `getElementsByClassName`, with *element**s***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the statement to

```js
const elem = ref.current.getElementsByClassName('myClass')
```

The function name includes `elements` (plural) and not `element`.
Also, it returns an array of all the matching elements.

Comment: If this is issue then voting to close as "unreproducible or caused by typo" is more appropriate.

Comment: Actually, a lot of javascript developers have this consudion. I don't know why!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a class in the component you would like to grab, then you can use `getElementsByTagName`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) for more methods.

For example:

```js
this.textInput.current.getElementsByTagName('textarea')
```